# How to make two apps Yii1 and Yii2 use the same session?

Tags: yii, yii2

I want to make a dashboard panel web in my existing website. The existing app is using Yii1 can be accessible via, let's say, `www.example.com`. I want to make `www.example.com/dashboard` using new app using Yii2. I already made the apache configuration.

But what's missing is the session. Users that logged in through Yii1 app will not be recognized in the dashboard.

How to make Yii1 and Yii2 use the same session data, i.e. user that logged in at Yii1 will be recognized in Yii2 vice versa?

**UPDATE**

The architecture is standard multiple web servers behind a load balancer.
The two app can be hosted in the same server instance (the config will be in the apache). Or they can be in different (the load balancer will handle the directory too).
But both will use the same memcache server for session storage. The apps also will use the same database, although the ActiveRecord implementation will obviously be in different code. As long as I can get the user ID of the current logged user, it should be okay.

Comment: Will both the application will be hosted in same server?

Comment: Updated the description. They can be and they can be not. But they will be in same domain. One will be in `www.example.com` and the other will be in `www.example.com/dashboard`.

Comment: did you solve this yet? i have the same issue. yii1 and yii2 share the same session

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to share session between two applications (Yii1 and Yii2). Here is how to do it if you are using `CDbHttpSession` in Yii1 and `yii\web\DbSession` in Yii2 (I didn't test it with other types of session storage, but it should work same):

- In Yii2 configuration for `yii\web\DbSession` for you application you should setup session name to be `PHPSESSID` so it can match one used by Yii1.
- Since in Yii1 CWebUser use prefix for storing logged user id and other things from user state, you should set this to be empty string (or what ever you can share between both application. Yii2 doesn't use prefix, so empty string works good too) `''`. You can do it by extending `CWebUser` and add something like this inside `public function init()`:

`public function init() {
    $this->setStateKeyPrefix('');
    parent::init();
}`

This is all what you need to be able to share session between two application.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is possible, I know yii2 has a setting for the cookie where the auth details is stored. You might be able to do the same thing in yii1

Take a look here 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/tutorial-shared-hosting.md#separate-sessions-and-cookies you want to do the oposite, share the cookie between them.

Btw I do not believe it is possible if the 2 apps are on different domains.

Another solution I can think of is to try to move the session to something like memcached and use the same key for both apps.

Also take a look here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html you might find something interesting. I believe you may be able to log the user in both places at once, that also might solve your problem.

Comment: Updated the server config. So how can we config the two app to use the same session (or maybe cookie) id to the memcache server.

Comment: If two application share same domain, sharing session between them by using CDbHttpSession/DbSession or memcache/redis like session storage is totally possible. It can be very useful in process of migrating big application from Yii1 to Yii2, since in that case you can migrate part by part. See my answer above for instruction how to do it.