# yii2 get user authentication from yii using session

Tags: yii, yii2

I have new system that ive been created using `yii2`. i want the existing system(using `yii`) able to send session into the new system(`yii2`). which means the new system will not ask for login if user already login in the existing system

Comment: have you try something? Because we don't know how do you implement your idea and what error or issue do you encounter. So plase read [mcve] and update your question.

Comment: @Sfili_81 is a pro now :D meanwhile addressing the issue you should google the problem before posting, anyway [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228403/how-to-make-two-apps-yii1-and-yii2-use-the-same-session) is one solution that can work for you.